# Load images from URL in list view adapter

Tags: android, http, bitmap, android-listview, drawable

I am gathering data from youtube's gdata API and would like to use the video's thumbnail.  I already have the urls for each of the thumbnails, however I am not able to get the images to show up in my listview.  The bitmap is currently not returning null, however I am not able to call the `imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` method with my current implementation (that I know of?).  Please help if you know of a better way to do this!  Thanks

```
public class ResultListActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String searchquery = null;
    Intent starter = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = starter.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        searchquery = extras.getString("search");
    }        
    final String URL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=5&alt=json&author=user&q=" + searchquery;
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>();
    final QueryYoutube query;       

    query = new QueryYoutube();
    boolean success = query.searchYoutube(URL); 

    if (success == false) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, no matching results found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ResultListActivity.this, YoutubeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } 

    int size = query.getNumberResults();
    HashMap<String, Object> row  = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Drawable d = null;          
        try {                   
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(query.getThumbnail(i)).getContent());
            bitmap.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
            d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        row  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        row.put("Thumbnail", d);            
        row.put("Title", query.getTitle(i));
        row.put("Description", query.getDescription(i));
        data.add(row);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.row,
              new String[] {"Thumbnail","Title","Description"},
              new int[] {R.id.thumb, R.id.title, R.id.description});
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytv://"+query.getVideoID(position)), 
                   ResultListActivity.this, OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
            startActivity(lVideoIntent);               
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would recommend doing this is that you should extend the `ArrayAdapter` class then in the `getView` method you fire off an `AsyncTask` to download the thumbnail in thread outside of the UI thread, then set the bitmap to the imageview in `onPostExecute`.

You should use something like `HttpUrlConnection` to get the `InputStream` for the image to decode into a `Bitmap`. If you are unsure about the dimensions of the `Bitmap` it is important that you check the size of the image before you actually create a `Bitmap` object that causes an `OutOfMemoryError` so beforehand set `BitmapFactory.Options` `inJustDecodeBounds` to `true` and then get the dimensions of the image then choose a sufficient `inSampleSize` and decode again to retrieve a `Bitmap` that is not too large.

You should also have some sort of `Bitmap` cache so that you don't have to always retrieve from the web.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for `SimpleAdapter`:

```
ImageView. The expected bind value is a resource id or a string and setViewImage(ImageView, int) or setViewImage(ImageView, String) is invoked.
```

You should supply the URI's to the images as the Thumbnail field, not the `Bitmap`s

```
Uri uri =  Uri.parse(query.getThumbnail(i)).getContent());
```

Comment: I am getting that the getContent() method is undefined for type Uri

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two ways:
1) you can implement your own list adapter with getView method, caching and async loading thubnails;
2) you have to make implementation of `SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder` interface.
Something like this:

```
private static class GrekViewBinder implements SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder
{
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation)
    {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.thumb)
        {
            ((ImageView)view).setImageXXX(... use `data` argument...);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }    
}
```

and bind this Binder to your adapter:

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new GrekViewBinder());
```